# My Login Screen is not working, blank screen

Tags: php, authentication

I am having an issue with my login screen for my website I am making. When I go to my login screen it is blank and says that there was an internal server error. Can anyone help?

here is my script:

```
<?php
  session_start();
  $user="customer";
  $pass="customer";
  if (isset($_SESSSION["logged_in"] && $_SESSION["logged_in"] == true)){
    header("Locataion: form.php");
  }
  if (isset($_POST["username"]) && isset($_POST["password"])){
    if ($_POST["username"] == $user && $_POST["password"] == $pass){
      $_SESSION["logged_in"] = true;
      header("Locataion: form.php");
    }
  }
 ?>
<html lang="en">
<body>
  <form class="login" method="post" action="login.php">
    Username:<br>
    <input type="text" id="username" name="username" required><br>
    Password:<br>
    <input type="password" id="password" name="password" required><br>
    <input type="submit" label="Login">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: A 500/Internal Server error is a generic error message and covers pretty much every single thing that can go wrong with a script. Check your server error logs to find out the exact error message.

Comment: Examine your first `if` condition carefully...

Comment: Any errors being returned by PHP?

Comment: Change your first `if` to `if (isset($_SESSION["logged_in"]) && $_SESSION["logged_in"] == true){`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Information about the problem:**

In `IF()`, you check if the variable is set with `isset()`, however, `isset()` must encompass your variable. the problem is that closing `isset()` is not correct it should end just after your first variable `$_SESSSION["logged_in"]`

**Solution:**

Replace:

```
if (isset($_SESSION["logged_in"] && $_SESSION["logged_in"] == true)){
  header("Location: form.php");
}
```

By :

```
if (isset($_SESSION["logged_in"]) && $_SESSION["logged_in"] == true){
  header("Location: form.php");
}
```

Good luck !

Comment: When you write an answer at least read it carefully before publish it because it contains more errors of the question :))

Comment: Thank you for your return, but I do not see my mistake, can you enlighten my lantern?

Comment: Thank you Jeremy! my parentheses were in the wrong place....I also misspelled location. It works now.

Comment: and `$_SESSSION`? :))))